# Elliptic Curve Cryptography in Java 6

Tags: java, cryptography, elliptic-curve

Is it possible to use Elliptic Curve Cryptography in Java 6 by default? I don't want use any third party providers like Bouncy castle.

Comment: Interesting question, but not one answer.

Comment: Oracle's Java 6 providers do not *provide* elliptic curve cryptography at all.

Comment: @AlexWien this is because Aslam has not specified any tags that have many followers...

Comment: You are supposed to accept answers and react to comments Aslam.  Please read the FAQ.

Answer (score 2):

The answer is a simple no, ECC functionality was not added until Java 7. Java 6 simply provided the API interface - a pretty well defined one at that - but not an actual implementation. That said, it may be usable through a PKCS#11 module (using the Sun PKCS#11 provider). But in that case you need a PKCS#11 compatible `.dll` which is probably unacceptable unless you are able to install a third party native library.

Answer (score 1):

In OpenJDK7 and Java 7 SE, basic ECC is fully supported according to [this page](http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk7/features/#f73). You still might have to add the JCA and export policy from an external .jar though because of US encryption export laws, it can't be in standard releases of Java but it is not technically a 3rd party provider since it is made by Oracle. Also note if you're not using NIST named curves, you'll most likely have to use a separate library.